# 4 while statements from 1 mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want the correct way to put query 
In the following way
Develop queries, for example,
time
11/06/06

11/01/06

11/04/05

pop

546

654

151

vistor

545

654

564

put all queries sporadically

```
     $sql = "select * from stat  where code = '3h211'  union select * from tmp_stat where code='3h211'    order by id desc   limit 5";
    $resursa = mysql_query($sql);
     $numR = mysql_num_rows($resursa);

    $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($resursa);

    if ($numR =="0"){


    echo "no data";
    exit(""); 
    }


    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resursa)) {



    $day = $rows['day'];

    echo "$day";

    }


echo "</categories>\n";



    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resursa)) {

    $pop = $rows['pop'];

    echo "$pop";


    }


echo "</categories>\n";



    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resursa)) {

    $vistor = $rows['vistor'];

    echo "$vistor";

    }

echo "</categories>\n";
```

Try this way
Shows only the first while
I know that bad programming
Because I am beginning to learn programming

Waiting for solution :)

Comment: "Waiting for a solution"?  That ain't "learning programming" ;)

Comment: `if ($numR =="0")` What what whyyyy???

Comment: -1: The first 11 lines of this question are pure gibberish. The code does nothing to clarify. The last sentence is... just no.

Comment: if ($numR =="0") if no data found

Comment: @10neen com: Yes but why on Earth do you have 0 as a string?

Comment: The result of the query 0    exit(""); The stop Query Is this wrong ?

Comment: @animuson *sigh*, unfortunately PHP does actually allow that. Look at the truth table [here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). However I agree that code like that should be discouraged as much as possible.

Comment: @10neen com - The function `mysql_num_rows()` returns an integer, not a string, so you should check `if ($numR == 0)` instead. Writing the 0 in quotes makes it a string and PHP has to convert this string to an integer first, before it can make the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
$days = $pops = $vistors = Array();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resursa)) {
  $days[] = $rows["day"];
  $pops[] = $rows["pop"];
  $vistors[] = $rows["vistor"];
}
```

Now you'll have all days in $days, all pops in $pops, etc. Verify with `print_r($days)`, et al.

Comment: bos - How can I display it by  this way http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/demos/Dashboard/Data/SalesCompare.xml


I used html
echo "<category Name='$day'/>\n";

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
mysql_data_seek($resursa, 0);
```

before each while loop. That resets it to row 0 for the next fetch.

Comment: How do I add this  mysql_data_seek($resursa, 0); 

Sorry I am new to programming

Comment: @10neencom: Before these lines: `while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resursa)) {`

Comment: Is this the way the query caused repeated 4 times

Comment: @10neencom: The query runs once, but mysql_data_seek takes you back to the first row of the results data so you can read through it again.

Comment: Problem has been resolved and thank for all

Comment: @10neen com - If that solved your problem, then mark it as the answer, to give some credit to the people trying to help you. Though, consider looping only once through the same dataset (answer of bos), no sense in keeping your server busy without any advantage.